# Ruby: run rake task to execute ruby scripts

Tags: ruby

I have a bunch of Ruby scripts and I'd like to start them with a Rake task.

A simplified version to illustrate my issue:

export_stats.rake:

```
desc 'Export statistics'

task :export_stats do
  puts "executing: export_stats.rb #{START_MONTH} #{END_MONTH} #{OUTPUT} #{ENVIRONMENT}"
  ruby "export_stats.rb #{START_MONTH} #{END_MONTH} #{OUTPUT} #{ENVIRONMENT}"
end
```

> rake aborted! elk-stack/export_stats.rake Don't know how to build task
>   'export_stats'

the export_stats.rb file is in same directory with export_stats.rake

the rake gem is installed and if I run

> rake export_stats

I get an error:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'export_stats'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: what is the output when you enter this `rake --tasks | grep export_stats`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you have a folder with some ruby scripts and you are trying to run a rake task that is located in the same folder. I assume you are not using any application framework like Rails (because you did tag the question only with "Ruby").

Do you have a Rakefile in same directory? If so does it contain a statement to load the specific files to run?

```
# Rakefile
#!/usr/bin/env rake
load 'export_stats.rake'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo.

The code says `export_stats`, and the error says `exports_stats`.

There's an extra `s`.

Read the error message carefully! ;)

Comment: thanks, I corrected the typo but the error persists.

Comment: In that case, I can't reproduce the problem.